# Post World War 2, did any country successfully annex territory of another sovereign country by force and retain it?

Tags: armed-conflict, dictatorship

[This article](https://www.yahoo.com/news/wartime-land-grabs-tend-end-121400871.html) claims:

> Wartime land grabs tend to end badly for tyrants, historian warns

The central thesis is as follows:

> “If a conquest is recognized internationally, the conqueror has a chance to hold on to new lands and bequeath them to future generations,” said Zubov.
>
> “If, however, the world refuses to acknowledge these annexations, anschlusses, unifications, and reunifications – if the conqueror simply starts drawing new borders of their empire during a war – it all tends to end very poorly and comically if we set aside the all the blood that is spilled in the process.”

The article goes on to cite Napoleon and Hitler as examples supporting the thesis.

However, I'm wondering if there are any counter examples in recent times (post world war 2)? Specifically, counter examples that meet the following criteria:

1. Invading country seizes land of another country by force.
2. Conquest is not internationally recognized.
3. Invaders retains the seized territory, in the long term,  despite international condemnation. (Let's say even after the death of the original "conqueror" political leader).

Comment: The history stackexchange might be an even better fit for this question.

Comment: I think you might be better to ask for examples that *don't* meet those criteria. Most countries were ruled by dictators (hereditary monarchs) until recently. International recognition was hardly a concept. And the conquerors often retained their territory for centuries. The conquest of most of Latin America in the name of the Spanish kings and queens world be one example.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is a better fit in History SE.

Comment: Basically whenever a map changed and no democracy was involved.

Comment: So what is a definition of dictator? At least more then 200 jears ago quite every country was run by a dictator if using todays definition.

Comment: @Trilarion OK, I have retracted my close vote.

Comment: To be on-topic here, the Q would need to specify a *recent* time frame.

Comment: @Obie2.0: correct, and dynasties continued to hold claims to lands they didn't actually occupy for centuries. English kings in re France, tsars in re Baltic city states etc. "International recognition" was indeed a pretty vague concept then... even though the pope had some level of that power, but that only applied to a narrow section of the states who cared. It became more of a thing in the 17th century. A certain Swedish king not being terribly well "recognized" because of the way he had seized power resulted in a protracted conflict (with Poland-Lithuania) etc. Also, the war of Spanish succ

Comment: Maybe Alasce-Lorriane meets your requirements? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alsace%E2%80%93Lorraine

Comment: UK, very broadly: Romans, Saxons, Vikings, French. Then the UK itself went on to claim about 1/4 of the Earth's landmass, some of which it still tentatively holds to this day.

Comment: Voting to Close as the question is too broad - the whole imperialism era was countries (even so called democratic ones like the British) successfully occupying and exploiting other countries and ruling it as their own with rampant political discrimination. As suggested by others add a time period so that this can be reasonably answered.

Comment: Wikipedia lists Golan Heights, East Jerusalem, Hyderabad, Goa and Tibet. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Annexation

Comment: @sfxedit: I've rolled backed your edits since you've broadened the Q even more, ironically after complaining that it's too broad. You've removed the "dictatorship" part which was rather central given the OP's tyrants quote that motivated their Q. They've also accepted an answer that satisfies their Q, so I find your edit totally counterproductive. Also, the Q was left closed by 3 other users (not incl. me), after your edits. You're welcome to ask your own Qs with different criteria.

Comment: @Tetsujin: what counted as "international [non-]recognition" in Roman or Viking times? I mean long wars were well known, e.g. the "100 years' war". Generally "international" suggests to me there were some third parties who cared (and voiced their views on the matter), besides the [two] warring ones.

Comment: @Fizz I made the edits after the question was closed. Adding a time-period of post-world war 2 makes the question easier to answer and more pertinent as colonialism was fading. The dictator part is irrelevant as even democratic countries have fought over territory and "illegally" occupy it (for example Israel and Pakistan). Let rain-willow decide if my edits are ok and then the rest of you can decide if the question is better and relevant here.

Comment: @sfxedit: it's not irrelevant if it contradicts the original author's intent. There's even an edit-reject reason for this.

Comment: @Fizz The Question was closed specifically because the dictator part made it too broad - in the 19th and 20th century "dictatorship" was common and aggressively occupying another country's territory was considered ok. It's only after post WW2 that has changed somewhat ("rule based" world order). The question is still pertinent without the dictator part. That is why I said leave it to the author to decide - if they want to rollback (and let the question be closed), I will ofcourse have no objection.

Comment: "The Question was closed specifically because the dictator part made it too broad." No that's not it. Take it to meta if you really believe that.

Comment: @Fizz You asked for a specific "time frame", convert asked for definition of dictator, Tetsujin talked about UK, Vikings, Romans, French etc., I pointed out about the imperialism era ... so aren't we all talking about how difficult it is to answer this question because democracy is only a recent modern phenomena and the earlier political systems were all kind of dictatorial?

Comment: @sfxedit: fair enough, I had missed that comment. Still invalidating highly upvoted/accepted answers or making them seem less relevant by changing the question later is [not good practice](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96560/significantly-edit-existing-question-or-ask-a-new-question-after-answer-accepte).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/143262/discussion-between-sfxedit-and-fizz).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Western Sahara seems to meet your requirements:

> Dictator

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morocco#Politics):

The Kingdom of Morocco is a monarchy with a Parliament and an independent judiciary.  Morocco was an authoritarian regime according to the Democracy Index of 2014.  The constitution grants the king honorific powers (among other powers); he is both the secular political leader and the "Commander of the Faithful" as a direct descendant of the Prophet Mohammed. He presides over the Council of Ministers; appoints the Prime Minister from the political party that has won the most seats in the parliamentary elections, and on recommendations from the latter, appoints the members of the government.  The constitution of 1996 theoretically allowed the king to terminate the tenure of any minister, and after consultation with the heads of the higher and lower Assemblies, to dissolve the Parliament, suspend the constitution, call for new elections, or rule by decree.

> seizes land of another country by force

On 6 November 1975 Morocco initiated the Green March into Western Sahara; 350,000 unarmed Moroccans converged on the city of Tarfaya in southern Morocco and waited for a signal from King Hassan II of Morocco to cross the border in a peaceful march. A few days before, on 31 October, Moroccan troops invaded Western Sahara from the north.

> Conquest is not internationally recognized.

On 18 December 2019, the Comoros became the first nation to open a consulate in Laayoune in support of Moroccan claims to Western Sahara. In January 2020, The Gambia and Guinea opened consulates in Dakhla; meanwhile, Gabon opened a consulate general in Laayoune. As part of the Moroccan-Israeli normalisation deal, the United States established a temporary consulate post in Dakhla in January 2021 as a transition to establishing a permanent consulate within the near future.

> Invaders hold the seized territory over the long term. (Let's say for two or more generations after the death of the original "conqueror").

Hassan II, King in 1975, only died in 1999, so only one generation.  However the way international recognition is going, it seems plausible that this occupation will last another generation.

Comment: Israel would qualify too. Nobody recognizes the occupied territories as part of Israel, but Israel is doing well without international recognition - but with ample support of the USA.

Comment: I would not describe Israel as a dictatorship, so did not use that.

Comment: Ups, yes, I forgot the part about dictatorships. Although it seems a spurious one, now that I think about it. The USA annexed Hawai the same way Russia did with Crimea, first sending the marines then sporting a referendum. Is it any better when a democracy does it?

Comment: @Rekesoft: well, the US also used nukes in the past [on the argument of not losing a lot of their people on the battlefield], so maybe Russia should do it too *now*? The US put out a lot of CO2 in the past to become #1, so why should China stop anytime soon? And yeah, the US had actual *slaves* in the past, so why shouldn't Russia or China now have some slaves too? For great justice.

Comment: @Rekesoft" And I almost forgot, the US put their Japanese population in internment camps, so why shouldn't China do that too now with the Uighurs, after all it's the US who declared that war on terror is eternal?

Comment: @Fizz OMG americans and their ultranationalism! Last week it's Obie 2.0, now it's you, both experienced users that should know better than replying to a comment in a way that doesn't help at all to the answer they are commenting upon - and in your case, you're doing to an old and buried post. I suggested Israel as a possible adition to this answer, they pointed to me that the original redaction of the question specified "dictatorships"; I apologized for not noticing that, then suggested that there's no reason why democracies shouldn't be included. Now, what the f*ck is your rant about?

Comment: @Rekesoft "Nobody supports" and "ample support of the USA" is contradictory. If enough countries(especially powerful ones) acknowledge the annexation, it becomes successful.

Comment: @Eugene True. Although enough countries in this case is "one". :) But in any case, Israel wasn't a valid answer at the moment I posted my comment. ;)

Comment: @Fizz they shouldn't do it for the same reason the US shouldn't do it

Answer (score 5):

- 1951 — [People's Republic of China annexes Tibet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Annexation_of_Tibet_by_the_People%27s_Republic_of_China)
- 1961 — [India invades and annexes Goa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Annexation_of_Goa) from Portugal.
- 1975 — [Indonesia invades and annexes East Timor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indonesian_invasion_of_East_Timor).  East Timor would regain its independence 27 years later.
- 1981 — Israel annexes the Golan Heights from Syria, after having occupied the region since 1967.  The annexation was later [recognized by the United States](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States_recognition_of_the_Golan_Heights_as_part_of_Israel), but condemned by the UN.

Comment: I don't believe South Ossetia & Abkhazia are considered part of Russia, even by Russia.

Comment: @Allure: You're right; they're allegedly "independent" countries.  I've removed that one from my list.

Answer (score 2):

*This answer was written before "Post World War 2" was added to the question*

I wonder if [War of the Pacific](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/War_of_the_Pacific) would qualify. Chile attacked Bolivia and Peru, eventually got peace/ceasefire treaty and eventually got to keep large parts of the country for good.

Chile was de jure Republic back then, but so is Russian Federation. Wikipedia mentions that transition to more representative parliamentary democracy only happened after this war.

Comment: On that angle, the US occupied the Philippines for two generation, around the same time.  I'm not even sure Chile qualified as much of a dictatorship at the time (1880s). Especially since they apparently had a change of leadership *during* the war (1881).

Comment: And can you explain how this war qualifies for "conquest is not internationally recognized"? I don't seen anything like that in the wiki page.

Comment: "Chile was also to occupy the provinces of Tacna and Arica for 10 years, when a plebiscite was to be held to determine nationality. ...Finally, in 1929, mediation under US President Herbert Hoover caused the Treaty of Lima to be signed by which Chile kept Arica, and Peru reacquired Tacna." - i.e. it was not recognized for around 30 years

Comment: Not recognized by whom? International recognition doesn't generally refer to the warring parties, but to third parties. Given that the war essentially contemporary with the European powers Scramble for Africa, it's hard to see how the'd have objected much... Interestingly, the only thing that Britain seems to have cared about (in re this war) was not being held responsible for acts of war with warships made in its dockyards...

Comment: And the mutual relations between Bolivia and Chile are still bad; they e.g. didn't have full diplomatic relations for 60 years. Recent Bolician presidents like Evo Morales wan't the 1904 treaty "scrapped" https://www.bbc.com/news/world-latin-america-22287222
But still that doesn't mean the resulting borders aren't *internationally* recognized.

Comment: It's also worth noting that there were two or three treaties involved. The [Treaty of Ancón (1883)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Treaty_of_Anc%C3%B3n)
was signed in the immediate aftermath of the war. But then Peru and Bolivia wanted to renegotiate that... So this is a good example of treaties not holding water much over time rather than other things the Q asks about. N.B. the 3rd treaty (the one mentioned by the BBC) is https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Treaty_of_Peace_and_Friendship_(1904)

Comment: @Fizz I assume that international recognition is the end game goal for an occupying party, and Chile shows it may be attained through a combination of successful offence, patience and political stability.

Comment: Interestingly Chile was the only country somewhat actively involved in the League of Nations, after it was founded in the aftermath of WW1. Most other Latin/South American countries seem to have considered the League largely irrelevant, at least according to a British report of the era. Brazil even formally withdrew. They were apparently not happy with article 21 explicitly mentioning the "Monroe doctrine" and the number of permanent seats that Europe had in the Council of the League https://www.jstor.org/stable/3015127

Comment: So a notion of "international recognition" is probably hard to define even in the interwar period, particularly in South America.

Answer (score -1):

The definition given in the OP doesn't necessarily constitute [*annexation*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Annexation), which is a legal term, when the territory is incorporated into a state. Thus, e.g., Golan Heights were annexed by Israel - *Israeli law applies on these territories*, their inhabitants obtained Israeli citizenship, etc.

On the other hand, Northern Cyprus or Guantanamo are held by force, but not incorporated into the states that hold them. In case of Guantanamo this was notably used to detain there terrorist suspects without giving them the same *rights that they would have under the US law, if they were on the US territory* (even if not US citizens) - subject that generated much controversy during the George W. Bush and later Obama administration (the latter tried first hold trials in the US, but then decided on transferring the inmates to other countries.)

Comment: Guantanamo doesn't fit this question. It wasn't taken by force. The second paragraph isn't very useful.

Comment: @Trilarion Guantanamo is held by force. But I think you missed the main point that I am making.